# AS3 Getter and companion setter in different namespaces

Tags: actionscript-3, getter-setter

I'm trying to create a property that can be `set` by extending classed and `read` publicly.

I couldn't think of a good naming convention for a `protected` property with a `public` getter, so I tried to do this:

```
public function get name():String{ return _name; }
protected function set name(string:String):void
{
    _name = string;
}
```

However I get the error (when trying to `set` `name` in an extending class):

> 1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property name through a
>   reference with static type testing:TestComponent.
>   1059: Property is read-only.

If I change the setter to `public`, it works fine.

Comment: does this class extends any class that have property "name"?

Comment: @ymutlu Nope, extends `Object`.

Comment: i ve added answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a slightly different approach to achieve what I wanted:

```
public function get name():String{ return _name; }
public function set name(string:String):void
{
    if(!_name.length)
        _name = string;

    else throw new Error("Property \"name\" can only be defined once.");
}
```

Now `name` will be defined within the extending class, but can't be set from then on.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know AS3 doesn't allow you to mix and match, both accessors should be the same.

I generally don't supply a setter to make the property read only, and directly set `_name` internally. Because it's protected, it will be accessible to descendants.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Kinda wanted to avoid the naming convention I use for privates though with the beginning `_` - just so it's tidier in my extending classes i.e. I can just do `name = "blah"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like below.

```
public class Test extends Object {
    protected var _name:String;
    public function get name():String {return _name;}
}

public class Test2 extends Test {
    public function set name(s:String):void {
        this._name = s;
    }
}
```